# Can an application using Dropbox Core API monitor a File Using Direct Link from Dropbox chooser?

Tags: dropbox, dropbox-api

My app, which is registered as a Dropbox Core API App  is limited to only its designated folder. I have a scenario where a user shares a  link  with my application using  Dropbox Chooser; this shared link is from a folder not  accessed by my core app. Can my app query the Dropbox Core API for this file to poll for changes ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible; the dropbox shared download link is only alive for a few hours.